# Writing good code question....?

Tags: java

I'm writing an app, and in many situations need to have direct access to *mainFrame*. It's ok if i'll do this(?):

```
public class Main {
private static JFrame mainFrame();
public static void main(String[] args) {
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              mainFrame = new JFrame(); //.... 
      });
}
 //...
public static JFrame getMainFrame() {
          return mainFrame;
}
}
```

I just think that is more easy to access *mainFrame* direct then to pass it like a reference.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the Singleton pattern if you only have one Main class and you will only have one JFrame in your application. A static variable is good enough on this case. Now, why do you need to get access to the mainFrame?

- Do you need to create child frames from that mainFrame?
- Do you need to display a message box and you want its parent to be the mainFrame?
- Do you have logic in that class?

If you have instance methods in your mainFrame, for example, and you need to access these methods from anywhere in your application, you could make these methods private, create public static methods, and make those static methods get the mainFrame instance and invoke the private methods. Maybe you should remove the logic from other places in your application and add it to the mainFrame class.

It all depends on what you do with this mainFrame object. What you have in place to get into it is not bad, in my opinion.

Comment: +1 - The key is to find out why access is required to the mainClass

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider implementing the Singleton pattern.  Extend JFrame to make your AppFrame class, and make that class a Singleton.  This is usually frowned upon, but is a solution to what you are looking to do.  Most GUI applications have a MVC architecture, and direct access to a View (i.e. the JFrame in your case) is restricted to the Controller classes.  You may want to read up on the MVC pattern if you are implementing a GUI based application.

Information on Singleton pattern [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).
[Information on MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)